# MS IIS6,self signed ssl installed successfully, but https doesn't work

Tags: ssl, iis-6

I follow the link below to install self signed ssl on window server 2003, IIS 6.

http://community.aspnix.com/windows-manuals-tutorials-tos/2669-create-self-signed-secure-socket-layer-certificate-ii6-windows-server-2003-a.html

I verified that the certificate installed successfully by viewing the certificate by going to  IIS > Web Sites > Default Web Site (or any site you assigned it to), right click > Properties > Directory Security > View Certificate.

When I go to https: I got

```
Internet Explorer cannot display the webpage
```

http works well. How can I get HTTPS to work in these circumstances?

Answer (score 2):

On the web site, go to *Properties* -> *Web Site* and under "Web Site identification" press the *Advanced* button. Add an entry under "Multiple SSL identities for this web site".

Answer (score 1):

Additional to Mathais's response at https://serverfault.com/a/382726/40488 you should add the certificate into the trust store for Internet Explorer, and whatever other browsers you are using.  This is important because more and more browsers are configured to deny self-signed certificates.

(Instructions for Internet Explorer on Windows 7)

1. Save the certificate on your desktop.
2. Right Click it
3. Select Install Certificate
4. Select Next
5. Select Automatically select the certificate store
6. Select Next
7. Select Finish